# Collatz Sequence nothing happens despite working in Python Tutor

Tags: python

For Automate the Boring Stuff chapter 3 there is a project to make a collatz sequence. The code I have made is as follows: On python tutor it seems to take a number and spit out a value, but when I run it in python after saying "Enter a number" and entering a value nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
def collatz(number):
    if number == 1:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 ==0:
        return number //2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number 

print('Enter a number')
number = int(input())
collatz(number)
```

**Update**: I was able to figure out why my collatz function wouldn't give a value. However now that I have this value how do I tell the system to take that value that was just given and put it back through the function again and again until the value 1 is reached. I tried a `while True` statement, but that only made the number go through the function once and repeat it adnauseum.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number == 1:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 ==0:
        return number //2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number + 1

print('Enter a number')
number = int(input())
print(collatz(number))
```

Comment: Regarding the update, that's a separate question. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but please try it yourself first and check out some other peoples' Collatz implementations. It's not hard :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing print, when calling `collatz(number)`, it should be `print(collatz(number))`.

Also input accepts an argument, which acts as print, 
so

```py
print('Enter a number')
number = int(input())
```

could be simplified as
`number = int(input('Enter a number'))`

Comment: YES that was it. Thank You. How would I tell it to take the number it gives me and keep throwing the number through the function until the value of 1 is achieved I tried a While True statement to run the function but it just continually repeats the returned value .

Comment: you should use recursion and instead of returning the value, if the number is NOT 1, return `collatz(value)`, so for the last two ifs, `return collatz(number//2)` and `return collatz(3 * number + 1)`